# create a backup of database every day using Cron. [putty]

Tags: backup, cron, putty

I have this code which created a backup of my database.

> pg_dump -U dbadmin -h 127.0.0.1 123telcom -f dbbackup

Now i want to create a backup every night.
Is there a way u can execute this code with crontab?

> 0 3 * * * pg_dump -U dbadmin -h 127.0.0.1 123telcom -f dbbackup

I'm new to putty so if anyone could help me a little that would be great.

Comment: put the command in a shell script and execute that from cron as you have stated 0 3 * * * (at 3am every day)

Comment: thanks. I made a script which works when I execute it manualy, but when I want to run it like this                                                                                   0 3 * * * /home/ruud/backup1.sh it says  -su: 1: command not found. Could u tell me what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Did you make it executable?

Comment: @ruud Did you ever get this working?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony yes. I put the file in the wrong directory. I used "crontab -e" and create my crontab there. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have fallen foul of cron's PATH set up.
If you look in /etc/crontab, it will define a PATH for itself and you will probably have a different PATH set up for your login.
Create your script with the first 2 lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

where the PATH includes whatever is set up in your environment and ensure that the script is executable.
To test what is going on try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

echo $PATH >> /home/yourhome/cron.txt
```

create an entry in /etc/crontab:

```
* * * * * root /home/yourhome/yourshell.sh
```

tell cron about the changes by using sudo crontab -e and then just save it and exit (often Ctrl O and Ctrl X if using nano editor) or I think that you can just `kill` the cron process and it will re-spawn.
Then check the cron.txt file to see what it is using for PATH.
PS Don't forget to remove this script from the crontab afterwards